# How to render elements from an array in separate tags?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, vue-native

I have a list of JSON objects in an array and I intend to render these elements inside the template tag in `Vue Native`.

My current output renders the elements without any spacing or any of the predefined CSS.

I am using a `v-for` loop to iterate through the elements and adding my results to a view tag containing other child tags inside.

The array looks something like this

```
[
 {
  "name":"A",
  "age": 23,
  "hobbies":{
   }
 },
 {
  "name":"B",
  "age": 26,
  "hobbies":{
   }
 }
]
```

In my template tag, I am iterating through this array using something like this

```
<template>
 <ScrollView>
  <template v-for="items in arr">
   <text>{{items.name}}</text>
  </template>
 </ScrollView>
<template>
```

Comment: Please post an example of the JSON and the Vue code.

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui i have updated the question with an example

Answer (score 1):

use array map:

```
<>
  {arrays.map(item=> <div>{item.title}</div>)}
</>
```

Comment: Using this, I run into a Component Exception error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

Comment: Hey! Got a work around by simply running the v-for outside the inner tags. Thanks for the help though!